# Jwplayer Stream is not working anymore

Tags: stream, jwplayer

this stream stopped working and now I'm getting a "connection failed" error.
Your help would be greatly appreciated, here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.tvradiogratis.com/canal/swfobject.js">     </script>

<div id="jwplayer1" style="position: absolute; overflow: hidden; left: 0px; top: 0px; width: 375px; height: 273px; z-index: 0;"></div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
                var so = new SWFObject('http://streamtv.gangahosting.com/player.swf', 'mpl', '375', '273', '9');
                so.addParam('allowscriptaccess', 'always');
                so.addParam('allowfullscreen', 'true');
                so.addParam('wmode','opaque');                      
                so.addVariable('logo', 'http://streamtv.gangahosting.com/img/logoplayer.png');
                so.addVariable('dock','false');
                so.addVariable('autostart', 'true');
                so.addVariable('abouttext', 'Player By GangaHosting.com');
                so.addVariable('aboutlink', 'http://streamtv.tvradiogratis.com/');
                so.addVariable('width', '375');
                so.addVariable('height', '273');
                so.addVariable('file', 'tvradiogratis-520533329');                    
                so.addVariable('logo.hide','false');
                so.addVariable('backcolor','cfe2f3');
                so.addVariable('frontcolor','000000');
                so.addVariable('screencolor','000000');
                so.addVariable('logo.link','http://streamtv.tvradiogratis.com/ver.php?id=-520533329');
                so.addVariable('logo.position','top-left');
                so.addVariable('stretching','exactfit');                 
                so.addVariable('streamer', 'rtmp://streamtv.tvradiogratis.com/tvradiogratis');
                so.addVariable('provider', 'rtmp');
                so.addVariable('controlbar','over');
                so.addVariable('quality','best');

                so.write('jwplayer1');
            </script>
```

Thanks!!

Comment: Your streaming server does not appear to be running. If I try to test out your stream is JW5 it fails to connect, and in JW6 it says that it can't connect to your server.

Comment: Thanks Ethan, what can I do? move the streaming server to another site?

Comment: What type of streaming server do you use?

Comment: I'm not an expert on the topic, please tell me where do I look for the type of streaming server

Comment: Sorry, but isn't this your stream? Or did you just find this stream online or something?